# Some Iconic French Poetry?

Tags: littérature, poésie, culture

I am looking for some poetry that is very iconic for French culture.. that every French kid knows. Or it can be a very famous speech in French literature. I need it for learning by heart for reading competition.

Answer (score 7):

Pour aller dans le sens d'un "very famous speech", je propose de faire un petit tour au théâtre, par exemple:

- [La tirade du nez](https://libretheatre.fr/tirade-nez-cyrano-de-bergerac/) (C’est un roc ! … c’est un pic ! … c’est un cap !) de *Cyrano de Bergerac*, d'Edmond Rostand.
- [La tirade de Don Rodrigue](https://libretheatre.fr/tirade-de-don-rodrigue-roi-cid-de-corneille-acte-iv-scene-3/) (Ô combien d'actions, combien d'exploits célèbres) et [le monologue de Don Diègue](https://libretheatre.fr/monologue-de-don-diegue-cid-de-corneille-acte-i-scene-4/)  (Ô rage ô désespoir, ô vieillesse ennemie) du *Cid*, de Corneille.

Answer (score 6):

First example that comes to my mind are the La Fontaine's Fables (les fables de La Fontaine) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Fontaine%27s_Fables .
If it does not fit your expectation of 'poetry', you can take a look at some poems from Rimbaud, Verlaine, Voltaire, Apollinaire, Hugo, etc.

But apart from La Fontaine's fables, I'm not sure you can pick a poem from the others I mentioned and say with almost 100% certainty that all French kids have learnt it.

Comment: La Fontaine's work is iconic literature in French culture, true, but it is not really poetry; rather, it is literature in verse. TLFi , _fable_ : Court récit allégorique, le plus souvent en vers, qui sert d'illustration à une vérité morale. Les Fables de La Fontaine, la morale d'une fable.

Comment: Certaines fables de La fontaine sont beaucoup plus connues que d'autres, par exemple *La cigale et la fourmi* ou "Le corbeau et le renard*

Comment: @LPH "Literature in verse" is arguably part of what is globally called poetry.

Comment: And there is no doubt *Dans un chemin montant, sablonneux, malaisé, et de tous les côtés au Soleil exposé, six forts chevaux tiraient un coche* is first class poetry.

Answer (score 5):

The others' suggestions are good ones, but just to give a different angle I would suggest poems that are taught to all pupils in French schools, which ensure everyone has heard of them.

A second criterium I would add is that they should be not too long, so that they can be learned rather easily.

With these criteria go the following ones:

- "Mignonne allons voir si la rose", easily the most iconic one of all times : https://poesie.webnet.fr/lesgrandsclassiques/poemes/pierre_de_ronsard/mignonne_allons_voir_si_la_rose
- "Chanson d'automne" : https://www.poetica.fr/poeme-1824/paul-verlaine-chanson-automne/
- "L'albatros": https://www.poetica.fr/poeme-127/charles-baudelaire-albatros/
- "Le dormeur du val": https://poesie.webnet.fr/lesgrandsclassiques/poemes/arthur_rimbaud/le_dormeur_du_val
- "L'invitation au voyage": https://www.poetica.fr/poeme-447/charles-baudelaire-invitation-au-voyage/

Answer (score 1):

Deux poésies me viennent immédiatement en tête :

- Liberté — *Paul Eluard*
- Le Pont Mirabeau — *Apollinaire*

Je pense que tous les français les ont entendues au moins une fois.

Answer (score 0):

There is not one single poet that can be said to have produced work as a whole that is iconic; rather, certain pieces have come to have a particular significance for certains persons. In the domain of war poetry, for instance can be noticed the following poem that elementary school children can relate to, while its realism is of interest to anyone.

[image]

Here is a list of such poems that might procure to you something proper to serve your goal: [43 classiques](https://www.poesie-francaise.fr/les-grands-classiques-de-la-poesie-francaise/).

Ce qui dure. Auteur : René-François Sully Prudhomme.

Le baiser (II). Auteur : Germain Nouveau.

Les baisers. Auteur : Germain Nouveau.

L'âme. Auteur : Germain Nouveau.

Dernier madrigal. Auteur : Germain Nouveau.

La feuille. Auteur : Antoine-Vincent Arnault.

La grand-mère. Auteur : Sophie d'Arbouville.

L'hirondelle. Auteur : Sophie d'Arbouville.

Le Pont Mirabeau. Auteur : Guillaume Apollinaire.

Chanson - J'ai dit à mon cœur. Auteur : Alfred de Musset.

Qu'en avez-vous fait. Auteur : Marceline Desbordes-Valmore.

Rosa fâchée. Auteur : Victor Hugo.

Il faut que le poète. Auteur : Victor Hugo.

Lorsque l'enfant paraît. Auteur : Victor Hugo.

Ô mes lettres d'amour. Auteur : Victor Hugo.

Les caresses des yeux. Auteur : Auguste Angellier.

Il n'y a pas d'amour heureux. Auteur : Louis Aragon.

Nous dormirons ensemble. Auteur : Louis Aragon.

Les yeux d'Elsa. Auteur : Louis Aragon.

Plaisir d'amour. Auteur : Jean-Pierre Claris de Florian.

À deux beaux yeux. Auteur : Théophile Gautier.

Chanson. Auteur : Pierre Corneille.

Quand vous serez bien vieille. Auteur : Pierre de Ronsard.

Bonjour mon coeur. Auteur : Pierre de Ronsard.

Mignonne, allons voir si la rose. Auteur : Pierre de Ronsard.

Le dormeur du val. Auteur : Arthur Rimbaud.

Le bateau ivre. Auteur : Arthur Rimbaud.

Éloge de l'amour. Auteur : Jean de La Fontaine.

Le lièvre et la tortue. Auteur : Jean de La Fontaine.

L'enfant prodigue (II). Auteur : Voltaire.

L'amour caché. Auteur : Félix Arvers.

Compagne savoureuse et bonne. Auteur : Paul Verlaine.

Es-tu brune ou blonde. Auteur : Paul Verlaine.

Mon rêve familier. Auteur : Paul Verlaine.

Art poétique. Auteur : Paul Verlaine.

Aimons toujours ! Aimons encore. Auteur : Victor Hugo.

Demain, dès l'aube. Auteur : Victor Hugo.

L'isolement. Auteur : Alphonse de Lamartine.

J'ai plus de souvenirs que si j'avais mille ans. Auteur : Charles Baudelaire.

Je t'adore à l'égal de la voûte nocturne. Auteur : Charles Baudelaire.

Hymne. Auteur : Charles Baudelaire.

Tristesse. Auteur : Alfred de Musset.

La nuit de mai. Auteur : Alfred de Musset.

Answer (score 0):

The first one that comes to my mind is [*Après la bataille*](https://www.poetica.fr/poeme-191/victor-hugo-apres-la-bataille/) by Victor Hugo.

(I learned it when I was ~15 yo, my children have it as school as well now - so it seems to still be quite popular)

Answer (score 0):

A few very iconic poems :

- Demain dès l'aube (Victor Hugo)
- Le dormeur du val (Arthur Rimbaud)
- Les feuilles mortes (Jacques Prévert)

Answer (score 0):

Comme je suis d'accord avec les autres réponses qui montrent les œuvres de Baudelaire, Corneille, Ronsard, Apollinaire, Hugo, et Verlaine, je ne souligne que quelques poèmes de *Paroles* par Jacques Prévert :

- Déjeuner du matin
- Le Cancre
- Page d'écriture
- Barbara